# links method does not exist using laravel pagination?

Tags: laravel-pagination

I am using pagination with Laravel 5.4 by this query.

```
$items = Item::with('likes')->whereStatus('1')->paginate(20);
```

And how i am rendering it in view

```
{{ $items->links() }}
```

this works fine on my local development,but on live serve i get this error

> ErrorException in Macroable.php line 74: Method links does not exist
>   (view file path)

Any help would be highly appreciated.